# Parameters mismatch in runtime dynamic linking

Tags: c++, windows

Trying to call a function in a custom dll, but getting different value at dll from what was sent by the app.

Testapp.cpp

```
typedef UINT(__cdecl* DoubleValFnc)(UINT);

HMODULE hdll = LoadLibraryW(L"my.dll");

DoubleValFnc df = (DoubleValFnc)GetProcAddress(hdll, "DoubleVal");

UINT someVal = 10u;
printf(fp, "Calling DoubleValFnc Sending value = %d\n", someVal);

UINT dv = df(someVal);

printf(fp, "DoubleValFnc Success, recieved value = %d\n", dv);
```

Mydll.cpp

```
UINT MyDll::DoubleVal(UINT someVal) {
    LOG("Value recieved from app = %d",someVal);
    return someVal * 2;
}
```

mydll.def

```
DoubleVal=DoubleVal
```

## dll log

Value recieved from app = -1

## APP output

Calling DoubleValFnc Sending value = 10

DoubleValFnc Success, recieved value = -2

Irrespective of what I send, the dll always recieves -1.

Comment: How is `MyDll::DoubleVal` declared in your class? Is it static?

Comment: making it static works. Thanks